# Mimic gestures on iOS and macOS by key codes

Tags: macos, ios, bluetooth, javascript

I want to send BLE key codes to mimic gestures on iOS and OSX such as swipe up and down. Is this possible?

Comment: Why the JavaScript tag? Are you able to simulate what you need from Xcode?

Comment: BLE as in Bluetooth Low Energy?

Comment: Yes. I wonder if there is a list of commands like the HID key codes?

Comment: BLE is the *connection*.  This is like asking if you can mimic sending HID codes over wires.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has UI recording for automated build testing, but you get that from Xcode and not necessarily on the device.

- https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/406/
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/09-ui_testing.html

There is quite a bit of setup, but I would start there and once you’re comfortable with the limitations, you can see about trying to make an app to automate from keyboard triggers.